# Any workarounds for lack of primary key on partitioned tables?

Tags: partitioning, postgresql-10

I am currently looking at implementing declarative partitioning with PostgreSQL 10. However, one sticking point is that we need to have a foreign key between two such partitioned tables, which is not supported. Is there any workaround or suggestions for alternative ways of doing this anyone can suggest? Or should we use table inheritance instead.

Thanks.

Comment: Table inheritance does not support a primary key either

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I can see you can have FK relationships defined at the parent level but this doesn't get enforced for child tables. So no advantage there to using inheritance instead!

Comment: Note that with the upcoming v11 you can at least have outgoing foreign keys, i.e. a partitioned table can _reference_ other (non-partitioned) tables. But unfortunately still no incoming FKs

Comment: Are you sure you need a partitioned tables? Partial indexes can get you a long way in Postgres without the need to use a partitioned table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. This is time series data, and were planning on a partition per month, So would this mean you would create a partial index per month, in our case?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. As long the `WHERE` condition in the queries matches the `WHERE` condition of the index, that should improve query performance. If however you want to partition for easier data archival or deletion (`drop partition` instead of `delete`), then this won't help

Comment: That's true, we do have a requirement to drop data after a period of time so using a form of partitioning makes this easier. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution is to make an exception and not add the foreign key. I guess this must be very large tables and there are usually not that many of them, so a few exceptions for better performance are typically acceptable. You could try to enforce the foreign key relationship with triggers, though it is messy. I don't know of a better alternative for PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: Thanks for that. It may well be that we drop the FK relationship seeing as though inheritance doesn't support it either.